# Change/adapt date widget on admin interface

Tags: python, django, date, widget

I'm configuring the admin site for my new app, and I found a little problem with my setup.

I have a 'birth date' field on my database editable via the admin site, but, the date widget isn't very handy for that, because it makes that, if I have to enter i.e. 01-04-1956 in the widget, i would have to page through a lot of years. Also, I don't want people writing the full date manually in only one edit box, as there are always problems with using dashes or slashes as a separator, or introducing date in European, American or Asian format...

What would McGyver ( I mean you ) do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [formfield_overrides](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) option to use a different widget.  For example (untested):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.DateField: {'widget': forms.TextInput},
    }
```

Then you'll need to do date conversion/validation yourself.

Comment: Nice!

Know any different date widget, or is there any online repository of widgets I can browse?

Thanks!

Comment: There are several widgets at http://www.djangosnippets.org including this one for splitting time fields into multiple inputs: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/590/  You should be able to use that for a nice Date widget.  There are also some projects that "collect" widgets into a single app, e.g. http://code.google.com/p/django-plus/ (can't think of any others atm).